# Are there generic terms or names to refer to elements of the domain, codomain, and range of a function?

Tags: functions, terminology

Say I have a function $f:A\rightarrow B$.

Is there some generic term or name for $x\in A$? (Something like "input" maybe? My goal is just to see if there's any standard term that's more succinct than "element of the domain".)

Likewise for $y\in B$? (Something like "possible output" maybe?)

And for $f(x)\in f(A)$? (I believe "value" is the correct term?)

Comment: $f(x)$ is the image of $x$ under $f$ or value of $f$ at $x$. I am not sure there are accepted general terms for elements of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: The terms you have suggested are as correct as any, but I wouldn't use the first two. You can't go wrong with "element of the domain" though.

Comment: @user251257 "a" and "b" :)

Comment: @AreaMan are you sure that it isn't $\alpha$ and $\beta$?